# Optimize linear function under quadratic (ellipsoid ) and boundary contraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given a linear function, I'm wondering how to get its maximal value under quadratic and boundary constraint.

Here is a more formally expression

$$\max \sum_{i=1}^N a_i x_i$$
$$s.t \quad \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i (x_i - \mu_i)^2 \le C$$
$$and \quad l\le x_i\le h, \quad\forall i={1,2,\dots,N}$$

where $N>0, a_i>0, \lambda_i>0, \mu_i, C>0, l>0, h>0$ are known.

when throwing the boundary constraint, i.e $l\le x_i\le h$ away, then it seems the problem becomes much easier, the target function gets its maximal value when $x$ is just on the boundary of the ellipsoid, so we may rewrite the quadratic inequality into an equal form, and finally gets $x_i$'s optimal value under a closed form solution.

But when adding the constraint for each $x_i\in[l,h]$, how can we solve this convex optimization problem in a efficient way? since $N$ might be a big integer, say millions or so.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Little remark : ellipse $\rightarrow$ ellipsoid

Comment: OK, I've update it

Comment: I would start with throwing this at a good quadratic solver (e.g. Cplex, Gurobi, Mosek).